# no hay datos disponibles en la tabla, la tabla de datos desaparece de las filas al buscar

Tags: javascript, html, datatables, tr

Estoy leyendo mucho sobre esto, la solución siempre es la misma primero llenar la tabla y luego llamar a Datatable, pero no puedo hacer que funcione para mí, mi problema es que llena la tabla pero Datatable no lo reconoce, al escribir en el cuadro de busqueda desaparecen las filas y no vuelvena cargarse mas a menos que refresque el navegador

Intenté llenar la tabla de diferentes maneras, siempre obtengo el mismo resultado.

**¿Cómo deberia llamar a Datatable para reconocer las filas?**

*Esto es parte de mi código.*

```
const DOMitems = document.querySelector('#items');
const productsUrl = 'http://localhost:5000/listproducts'

let fetchProducts = async () => {
   const response = await fetch(productsUrl);
   if (response.status !== 200) {
     throw new Error("cannot fetch data");
   }
   let datashops = response.json();

   return datashops;
 };

function  renderizarProductos() {
   fetchProducts()
   .then((datashop)=> {
       datashop.forEach((item) => {  
       
         
           // Estructura
           const miNodo = document.createElement('tr');
            miNodo.classList.add('text-info');
         
           const miNodoCardBody = document.createElement('td');
          
           // Titulo
           const miNodoTitle = document.createElement('td');
         miNodoTitle.innerHTML += item.code_name; 
        
           // Imagen
           const miNodoimg = document.createElement('td');
           const miNodoImagen = document.createElement('img');
           miNodoImagen.classList.add('img-fluid');
           miNodoImagen.setAttribute('src', '/images/products/'+item.image);
           // Precio
           const miNodoPrecio = document.createElement('td');
          /*  miNodoPrecio.classList.add('card-text'); */
           miNodoPrecio.innerHTML += (parseFloat(item.price.$numberDecimal)).toFixed(2);

           const miNodoStock = document.createElement('td');
           miNodoStock.innerHTML += item.stock;
           // Boton 
           const miNodoBtn = document.createElement('td');
           const miNodoBoton = document.createElement('button');
           miNodoBoton.classList.add('btn', 'btn-primary');
           miNodoBoton.innerHTML += '+';
           miNodoBoton.setAttribute('marcador', item._id);
           miNodoBoton.addEventListener('click', addProductsToCar); 
           // Insertamos
           
           miNodo.appendChild(miNodoTitle);
           miNodo.appendChild(miNodoPrecio);
           miNodo.appendChild(miNodoStock);
       /*     miNodoimg.appendChild(miNodoImagen); */
    /*        miNodo.appendChild(miNodoimg);   */                      
           miNodoBtn.appendChild(miNodoBoton);
           miNodo.appendChild(miNodoBtn);
    
           DOMitems.appendChild(miNodo);
          
       });       
   });
$('#sellproducts').DataTable(); 
}

renderizarProductos();
```

Esto es el **HTML** para datatable

```
<table id="sellproducts" class="table" style="width:100%">
                        <thead>
                            <tr class="text-dark">
                                <th>Producto</th>
                                <th>precio</th>
                                <th>Stock</th>
                                <th>add</i></th>                               
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody id="items">


                        </tbody>
                        <tfoot>
                            <tr class="text-dark">
                                <th>Producto</th>
                                <th>precio</th>
                                <th>Stock</th>
                                <td>add</i></td>                                
                            </tr>
                        </tfoot>
                    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo resolvi, para que los datos carguen antes que Datatable, subi una linea a la inicializacion de datatable

Asi que mi codigo

```
         DOMitems.appendChild(miNodo);
          
       });
$('#sellproducts').DataTable();       
   });
}
```